# ElasticSearch duplicating indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

(Read this article first [How to use Elastic Search on top of a pre-existing SQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856457/how-to-use-elastic-search-on-top-of-a-pre-existing-sql-database)) I'm currently working with MySql, but I'm trying to change to use ElasticSearch as our search engine. I'm migrating a table through the [Elastic Search River JDBC](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) to elastic search using the following curl request:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/table_river/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
    "url" : 'localhost:9200/blah', "user" : "x", "password" : "x",
    "sql" : "select some_field as _id, * From some_table",
    "index": "some_index",
    "type" : "some_type",
    "schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *"
}
}'
```

To keep elastic search and the mysql table in sync, I'm using the schedule parameter to run every minute and pull the table into elastic search, but during the execution Elastic Search creates duplicate indexes and I get the following:

```
complete: river jdbc/table_river metrics: 21123 rows
```

After a minute, the river executes once more I get the following response:

```
complete: river jdbc/table_river metrics: 42246 rows
```

My "index_total" increments from 21125 to 42248 to 63371, but the total number of documents remains the same: 21125

I might not be doing things properly. I will accept a url to an article first rather then someone just telling me how to. I did some fair research first.

[Avoid rebuilding index through jdbc-river on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714588/avoid-rebuilding-index-through-jdbc-river-on-elasticsearch)

[elasticsearch data increase & duplicate at each restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26174920/elasticsearch-data-increase-duplicate-at-each-restart)

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate indices? can you try to describe what you are trying to do? and maybe add some log errors

Comment: Made a quick update to my description, hope you can help me out

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood how the Elasticsearch JDBC river plugin actually works. Why do you need to keep your database and elasticsearch in-sync? How often do you insert/update elements in your database?

Comment: Btw the answers in the link you post are not very accurate. What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Inserts/Updates are not made that often, but I flatten out various tables that make up a table with about 1 million rows and I want to be able to query that table pretty efficiently through ES API implementation of Lucene's full-text search engine. But I don't want to have inconstancy in data using ElasticSearch and MySql database so I'm not sure how to tackle that problem.

Comment: What you have to know is that if you are using a river between MySQL and ES, you can't have Real Time search. You'll just benefit from the search performance of elasticsearch since the data will be already indexed in your cluster. Thus you'll have to define a time when your data will be indexed and how much fresh do you need it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is going to be really inefficient to re-index all the data from a table into ES every minute.  What I suggest instead is that when you insert/update from mySQL put the primary key for that table into a queuing system (we use rabbitMQ).  You can then have 1, 2, or 100 rabbit consumers who take the data, transform it in some way, and then insert into ElasticSearch.

The beauty of this solution is that it solves the problem for both new and existing data.  To backfill the entire table simply insert all the primary keys into your queue and let your queue consumers fill in ElaticSearch.

Also, this way you're only doing work when you need to be, not every minute.